# Changing Variables in Multiple Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

On a test I had a question where the unit square $[0,1]^2$ in $u,v$-space was being transformed by something like $T(u,v)=(uv,v)$ into a new region in $x,y$-space (for a double integral).

I had to find the image of the transformation, and intuitively I thought: well, clearly $$0\le uv\le 1$$ $$0\le v\le 1$$ so the image must be the unit square.

Luckily I caught my error, and ended up realizing that the image was actually a *triangle* in the $x,y$-plane.

My question is: how can one systematically go about finding the image of a transformation from $R^n\to R^n$? It's not that I don't like actually "thinking," but I feel like there must be some more methodical way of going about these problems.

Alternatively, is there a way to find the bounds of integration without bothering with the region itself?

Comment: It's not a triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrize the border and compose with the transformation.

Comment: Can you always focus exclusively on the border? I've had a little topology and I think I remember that borders get sent to borders under continuous transformations (maybe there are some more conditions)... is that right?

Comment: The transformation is a diffeomorphism, so is bijective and the inverse is continuous.

Comment: Why is focussing on the border simpler (if I understand your point correctly) than the standard approach?

Comment: @Did Because you just have to find the image of the border curves, without worrying about the interior of the region.

Comment: But this is exactly as simple as the full job, no?

Comment: My studendts find that only equalities is easier.

Answer (score 1):

> Express the old variables as functions of the new ones and deduce the domain where the new ones "live".

In your case, $(x,y)=(uv,v)$ hence 
$$(u,v)=(x/y,y),$$ and the $(u,v)$-domain is defined by $$0\leqslant u\leqslant1,\qquad 0\leqslant v\leqslant 1,$$ hence the $(x,y)$-domain is defined by $$0\leqslant x/y\leqslant1,\quad 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1,$$ or, more simply,
$$
0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant 1.
$$